# Run shutdown script as Administrator on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, batch, shutdown, administrator

I've written a script using Ninite Pro to update the installed Applications on the Windows XP pro Client.

Unfortunately it has no administrator privileges, is there a way to run a shutdown script as administrator?

I've tried:

> runas /user:Admin /savecred

but that didn't do it. Any hint would be great.